# Ansible: How do you populate a variable with the value of a pattern/substring on a line in a remote file?

Tags: ansible, ansible-role

I have a remote server with a file on it. One line in that file is the following:

```
authorizationToken=<hash or empty string>
```

I'd like to set a variable in a role to the value of whatever's after the equals sign on that line, if anything (it might be a hash, or it might be an empty string).

What's the least awful way to do this?

Comment: dup https://stackoverflow.com/a/44260130/2795592 ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Konstantin linked you to a solution using custom facts, but you can also get at the same value using a simple task like:

```
- name: get authorizationToken
  command: >
    awk -F= '$1 == "authorizationToken" {print $2}' /path/to/configfile
  register: token
```

Now the value is available in subsequent tasks as `token.stdout`.

Comment: Hah, we came to the same conclusion. :)

Comment: Well, sure, although I posted this an hour ago.  Since it looks like you adopted this solution, maybe you want to mark this as the accepted answer?

Answer (score 0):

After trying for a while to do this the "right" way, in the end the path of least resistance was using a shell script:

```
- name: Record autorization Token
  shell: "cat {{ buildagent_dir }}/conf/buildAgent.properties 2>/dev/null | grep authorizationToken | cut -d '=' -f 2"
  register: token
```

Comment: Note that you don't need `cat` in any case, and by using `awk` you can replace *both* the `grep` and `cut`, and since you're now down to a single command you can replace `shell` with `command`.

Comment: I know it's not the most character-efficient way of doing it, but I generally prefer explicitness and readability to efficiency when writing shell commands, and I find awk syntax to be tougher to parse at a glance. Maybe I'm weird.